# Reading Web Services URLs from a text file C# NAV

Tags: c#, web-services, erp, dynamics-nav, navision

I am using Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2009 as I am building a C# program as the integration. Currently Im defining all my web service references inside my C# code.

I wanted to know whether I can call the web service references from a text file since I will be using different URLs with different domains. Currently Im running on localhost.

Comment: "Call the ... references from a text file"  I do not understand what you mean by this.  Do you mean read the text file with the web service and launch the URLs?

Comment: No. Read the text file(s), extract the URL and start the services.

Comment: how are you hosting the services? self hosted? or IIS?

Comment: Self hosted. Currently its on localhost, soon will be shifted to a different host which will be a non IIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the hard-coded URLs that were created when you set the reference to the web service - you certainly can. Your web service proxy has a Url property that you could populate with an alternative web service URL, e.g. one read from a text or config file, prior to the actual web service call.